# Laravel Passport Multi Authentication

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-7

I want to create a multi-authentication web app in Laravel using Passport.

I was able to complete the login process of two different guards **api** and **admin-api**. The important part is that both of the guards use **oauth_access_tokens** table in the database which is created by passport which has a field called **user_id**.

This means that whenever we call the **logout** method for either user if the other happens to have the same **id**, because admins table is different from users table, the login token will be destroyed for both. Because in the models of each of Admin and User we are refering to a function `AauthAcessToken`:

```
public function AauthAcessToken()
{
    return $this->hasMany('\App\OauthAccessToken');
}
```

**And** `OauthAccessToken` is the model of the table `oauth_access_tokens`.

So I manually created a new table `admin_oauth_access_tokens` which is a replica of `oauth_access_tokens` and reffred to it in Admin model function `AauthAcessToken`. But that didn't solve the problem so I deleted the `admin_oauth_access_tokens`.

**How can I fix that?**

**Here is some code:**

**auth.php**

```
    <?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],

        'admin-api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 15,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

**Auth\PassportAuthController.php:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;

class PassportAuthController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['generateAccessToken', 'login']]);
    }

    protected function generateAccessToken($user)
    {
        $token = $user->createToken($user->email.'-'.now());

        return $token->accessToken;
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email|exists:users,email', 
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        $credentials = [
            'email' => $request->email, 
            'password' => $request->password
        ];

        if( Auth::attempt($credentials) ) {
            $user = Auth::user();

            $token = $user->createToken($user->email.'-'.now());

            return response()->json([
                'token' => $token->accessToken
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
           Auth::user()->AauthAcessToken()->delete();
        }

        return response()->json([
            'msg' => 'Logged out complete'
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Auth\Admin\PassportAuthController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;

class PassportAuthController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:admin-api', ['except' => ['generateAccessToken', 'login']]);
    }

    protected function generateAccessToken($user)
    {
        $token = $user->createToken($user->email.'-'.now());

        return $token->accessToken;
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email|exists:admins,email', 
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        $credentials = [
            'email' => $request->email, 
            'password' => $request->password
        ];

        if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($credentials)) {
            $user = $this->guard()->user();

            $token = $user->createToken($user->email.'-'.now());

            return response()->json([
                'token' => $token->accessToken
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
           $this->guard()->user()->AauthAcessToken()->delete();
        }

        return response()->json([
            'msg' => 'Logged out complete'
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during authentication.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('admin');
    }
}
```

**Thanks**

Comment: Can you add `User` and `Admin` model definition to the question? Or just `AauthAcessToken()` method code?

Comment: That is right I will add all that part up one second

Comment: @VaibhavrajRoham fixed

Comment: That seems to be a little complex, please check out this issue https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/161

and this PR https://github.com/laravel/passport/pull/1220

Comment: @VaibhavrajRoham I'll check thanks